# HP ALM 12:53 - Avoiding login form for authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, alm, fetch-api

I want to authenticate against HP Alm but when running the code in a browser a popup appears telling me to manually log in. That acutally works, I can send request afterwards, all good.

But how do I avoid that? I want it to authenticate without that browser login form. Any ideas? Thank you!

Best regards,
Daniel

```js
import utf8 from 'utf8';
import base64 from 'base-64';

class AlmApi {
    static getAllDefectsFromAlm() {
        performSignIn();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        return fetch(request, {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: headers
        })
         .then(response => response.json())
         .catch(error => console.log('Getting data failed: ' + error.message));
    }
}

let alm_host = '<URL><PORT>/qcbin';
let sign_in = alm_host + '/api/authentication/sign-in';
let sign_out = alm_host + '/api/authentication/sign-out';
let request = alm_host + '/rest/domains/<DOMAIN>/projects/<PROJECT>?<QUERY>';

let username = 'USERNAME';
let password = 'PASSWORD';
let login_credentials = username + ':' + password;
let bytes = utf8.encode(login_credentials);

let headers = new Headers();

function performSignIn() {

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic' + base64.encode(bytes));
    fetch(sign_in, {
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        mode: 'no-cors'
    })
     .then(response => response.json())
     .catch(error => console.log('Authorization failed : ' + error.message));
}

function performSignOut() {
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    fetch(sign_in, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers
    })
     .catch(error => console.log('Logout failed: ' + error.message));
}


export default AlmApi;
```

Comment: Using `mode: 'no-cors'` with your `GET` request in `getAllDefectsFromAlm` causes the browser to block your code from any access to the response. So your `.then(response => response.json())` isn’t gonna work. Same for your `POST` request in `performSignIn`; the `.then(response => response.json())` will fail there too—the `POST` request itself will succeed, but your browser won’t let your code access the response.

Comment: Actually the other effect of setting `mode: 'no-cors'` on the `performSignIn` `POST` request is that your browser won’t let you add any request headers to that request that aren’t CORS-safelisted requests headers https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header. So that POST request gets sent without the `Authorization` request header you’re trying to add, and also without the `Content-Type: application/json` you’re trying to add. So I guess that `POST` request is going to fail authorization and would not be sent with the right content type even if it didn’t require authorization.

Comment: Well, commenting out no-cors results in a 501 - but I don't get the pop up anymore...

Answer (score 0):

I would always refer to the REST API manual from HP, in particular for your version:

http://alm-help.saas.hp.com/en/12.50/api_refs/REST/#sign_in.htm

In particular please check your header. You do not need some parameters as above reported.

Then try to login as again and you should be able to get access without pop-up interface coming up ;)

I had the same long time back with QC 11.52 version ;) there the authentication with a POST action under  /authentication-point/authenticate

Thus please check in your case which are the correct ulr and parameters/headers to be used.

hope this help you a bit. Have a nice day!

Comment: The above ALM Help link does not function anymore.

Comment: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/15.5-15.5.1/online_help/Content/APIs/API_ALM_REST_Site_Admin.htm     
Is the new reference for QC 15.x